# How to read a text file and store it in a two-dimensional list Using Python?

Tags: python, list, file, multidimensional-array, readfile

I'm trying to read data from an existed text file, then I want to print it as a triangle shape.

**distance_matrix.txt**:

```
[0]

[1, 0]

[13, 12, 0]

[17, 16, 10, 0]

[16, 15, 8, 1, 0]

[13, 12, 4, 5, 4, 0]

[12, 11, 6, 11, 10, 6, 0]
```

- First, I opened the text file then read it and stored it in a list:

```
file1 = open("distance_matrix.txt", "r")
   contents1 = file1.readlines()
```

- Next, I have tried to split each number by itself so I can store it in a two-dimensional list:

```
for i in contents1.split(", "):
     numbers = re.split(', |\[|\]', i)
     numbers.remove('')
     numbers.remove('\n')
     for j in contents1[i]:
          numbers.append(contents1[i][j])
          print(contents1[i][j])
```

But this isn't working!

In conclusion, what I'm trying to do here is to read each line from the text file then split each number and put it in a matrix.

Comment: do you want to extract the lists ?

Comment: Does your file actually contains those lists? the braces?

Comment: How's the data being divided?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it’s too vague and ambiguous. What does _this isn’t working_ mean, exactly? Have you done any research there are mountains of guides and tutorials on this. Also, use a context manager to handle the file object, and don’t use `readlines()` if you plan on iterating over each line anyway.

Comment: Basically I have these numbers in **distance_matrix.txt** as shown above in a triangle shape. I want to read that file and store each number individually in a  matrix where I can access each number by its position, for example: number[1][1] which will give me 0

Comment: @WhitePuzzle please see my edited solution once the question is clearer

Answer (score 0):

Use `json` to parse a list from a string.

```
import json
filename = "distance_matrix.txt"
f = open(filename,"r")
lines=f.readlines()

result_matrix = []
for line in lines:
    result_matrix.append(json.loads(line))

print(result_matrix)
#[[0], [1, 0], [13, 12, 0], [17, 16, 10, 0], [16, 15, 8, 1, 0], [13, 12, 4, 5, 4, 0], [12, 11, 6, 11, 10, 6, 0]]
```

Comment: Use a context manager to handle the file object, and you can get rid of `readlines()`, it’s just extra work for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following, this solution uses the `re` library where you can read more about it in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

arr = []
file_name = "dist_mat.txt"
with open(file_name, 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        matches = re.findall("(\d+)", l)
        arr.append(list(map(int, matches)))
print(arr[0][:])
print(arr[1][:])
print(arr[2][:])
```

which will give you the following output:

```
[0]
[1, 0]
[13, 12, 0]
```

Now every line is stored in the array as you want, `arr[pos_i][pos_j]`